# Express + Socket.IO + RabbitMQ (node-amqp)

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm having a hard time putting all these three together, probably because I'm not getting properly the concept of routing with Express.

I have a RabbitMQ queue with event updates. We can recognize these events by their id. So I want to get on a given page about an event, just the updates corresponding to its id.

Queue: 1316, 1539, 3486, 3479, 1316, 3890, 3479, ... -> Feed from the DB indefinitely.
www.example.com/event/1316 -> Gets from the queue just messages with id 1316
www.example.com/event/3479 -> Gets from the queue just messages with id 3479

My code works good when I load the first event, but when I load the second one in a different window, it gets messages from both events, and if I load a third one, guess right, it gets messages from the three ids.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express')  
, http = require('http');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, { log: false });
require('./io')(io);

var amqp = require('amqp');
var rabbitMQ = amqp.createConnection({ host: 'localhost' });

rabbitMQ.on('ready', function() {
  console.log('Connected to RabbitMQ');
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Socket connected: ' + socket.id);
    rabbitMQ.queue('offer', { autoDelete: false, durable: false, exclusive: false }, function(q) {    
      q.bind('#'); // Catch all messages    
      q.subscribe(function (message) {
        obj = JSON.parse(message.data.toString());
        //socket.broadcast.to(obj.id).emit('message', obj);
        io.sockets.in(obj.id).emit('message', obj);
      });
    });
  });
});

var routes = require('./routes')
, event = require('./routes/event');

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/event/:id', event.index);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

**io.js**

```
var socketio = function (io) { 
  if (!io) return socketio._io;  
  socketio._io = io;
} 

module.exports = socketio;
```

**routes/event.js**

```
var io = require('../io')();

exports.index = function(req, res) {
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.join(req.params.id);
  });
  res.render('event', { title: 'Event' });
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying and failing, I have understood what I was doing wrong cause using `io.sockets.on('connection')` inside of the router was duplicating the event. So at the end, the simplest way of thinking is the right one.

**app.js**

```
var room = '';
var roomHandler = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.path.match('event')) {
    room = req.params.id;
  } 
  next(); // Passing the request to the next handler in the stack.
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {    
  socket.join(room);
});

rabbitMQ.on('ready', function() { 
  rabbitMQ.queue('offer', { autoDelete: false, durable: false, exclusive: false }, function(q) {      
    q.bind('#'); // Catch all messages  
    q.subscribe(function (message) {
      obj = JSON.parse(message.data.toString());
      io.sockets.in(obj.id).emit('message', obj);
    });
  });
});

app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/event/:id', roomHandler, event.index);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving them all because you `join` but never `leave` the room.  If you look at [Socket IO Rooms](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) from the wiki, at the bottom, it provides `io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]` as a way to get a list of rooms that the socket has joined (which I suspect will include all three if you've visited all three links).

You might want to try going through this list of rooms and `leave` any that aren't the current room, and see if that solves the problem.

### Edit

Ok, so, there are two reasons/solutions to this.  I just tested my theory, and it is valid - you receive messages for each room you've `join`ed, and will continue to do so until you `leave` them.  So here are the options:

#### 1. `leave` all other rooms when they `join` a room

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    var room = req.params.id;

    var roomKeys = Object.keys(io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]);
    roomKeys.forEach(function(key) {
        if (key === '' || key === '/' + room) return;
        socket.leave(key.slice(1));
    });

    socket.join(room);
});
```

As said, I tested this.  It works.

#### 2. Don't send a `message` event, send a `{room name}` event

Instead of emitting a 'message' event, you could emit a '{room name}' event.  Instead of your `q.subscribe()` callback containing `io.sockets.in(obj.id).emit('message', obj);`, you would just do `socket.emit(obj.id, obj);` and you'd have the javascript client only listen for that page's event types (based on the URL path).

I also tested this.  It also works.  It's also simpler (I think) because it only requires the `.emit()` in your `q.subscribe()` callback, which means you save the 'room management' stuff.

Comment: But I don't want to leave the room. What I want is for every event page, to have a room with its id where I broadcast all the messages containing that id.

Comment: I believe though that your connected clients are joining each room they visit, but are not unjoining when they leave the page, so going to `/event/1234` and then `/event/2345` means they are joined to both rooms, so therefore they get both feeds to the browser - which is what you're seeing, right?

Comment: So now I'm even more lost. Let's say I want to have five events in five different windows. As I understand each of them creates a new socket. And what I want is for each of this sockets to have a different room (or another solution), because on an event page I just want to get the event updates corresponding to its id. So I don't understand why when I load the second window this socket is subscribed also to the first id.

Comment: All of the `/event/nnnn` pages use the same socket.  When you switch from one page to another, you are still on the same socket, so you are still connected to any rooms you had previously joined using that socket.  So when you call `.join()` to join the new room, it adds the new room - but you are _still a member of the previous room_ so you still get those messages.  Because it is all the same socket, leaving a page does not mean leaving a room.  Does that make it clearer?

Comment: But I load every event on different windows having several of them open at the same time and I can see in the server, that those sockets have different id.

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can better explain it - whether or not the socket IDs are different, this is what's happening.  Try `console.log()`ing `io.sockets.manager.roomClients[socket.id]` and go bounce around a bunch of pages - you will see that the list grows to include every 'room' (page) you've visited, which means the client gets all those messages.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I see that, but I would like to understand why it behaves like that.

Comment: Ok, I'm using your first solution which works good, but still I don't understand the whole behaviour of this. For example, if I use this `console.log('A socket with id: ' + socket.id + ' connected!');` inside of `on('connection')`, when I load the second event this is printed two times, and then if I load a third page this is printed three times, etc.